# EF Core 6 - Error when creating relationship in dbContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Here is the relationship I need to create
[this Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNGcJ.png)

And here are the entity classes for each table

The Airport table:

```
[Table("Airport")]
public class Airport
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FlightSchedule> DepartureAirports { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FlightSchedule> ArrivalAirports { get; set; }
    public Airport()
    {
        DepartureAirports = new List<FlightSchedule>();
        ArrivalAirports = new List<FlightSchedule>();
    }
}
```

The Flight Schedule table:

```
[Table("FlightSchedule")]
public class FlightSchedule
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid DepartureAirportId { get; set; }
    public Airport AirportDepart { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ArrivalAirportId { get; set; }
    public Airport AirportArrival { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
    public FlightSchedule()
    {
        Flights = new List<Flight>();
    }
}
```

And here is my config for DbContext in OnModelCreating() method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Airport>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<FlightSchedule>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.HasOne(e => e.AirportDepart)
            .WithMany(e => e.DepartureAirports)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.DepartureAirportId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

            entity.HasOne(e => e.AirportArrival)
                .WithMany(e => e.ArrivalAirports)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ArrivalAirportId)
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
        });
```

The diagram built from SQL server looks like what I designed but when I add some data seeder for those 2 tables, only Airport works, Flight Schedule would produce this error

> No relationship from 'Airport' to 'FlightSchedule' has been configured by convention because there are multiple properties on one entity type - {'ArrivalAirports', 'DepartureAirports'} that could be matched with the properties on the other entity types - {'AirportArrival', 'AirportDepart'}. This message can be disregarded if explicit configuration has been specified in 'OnModelCreating'.

I suspect maybe my configuration is wrong but I'm not sure where the cause is, since this is my first time trying with code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table `FlightSchedule`, columns `DepartureAirportId` and `ArrivalAirportId` need to be set up at **nullable**.

A record in `FlightSchedule` table can have only one of these values, not both.

Comment: Aren't all flights should have a source and a destination?

Comment: it's true in reality, but in your case, when you add an `Airport` object with some `ArrivalAirports` items, these items would have the same FK `ArrivalAirportId = <ID-of-inserted-Airport-record>`, but they don't have values for `DepartureAirportId`, and it violates the constraint `[Required]`

Comment: I just finish the last step, it really works as you said, but the problem is if I set them as nullable, one of them would have a null value on the DB. How can I update them with the same FlightSchedule ID?

Comment: with your current configuration,
 table `FlightSchedule` contains data about Departure and Arrival, but a record in this table keeps only information about Departure, or Arrival, not both.

And obviously, records of Arrival and Departure of a Flight won't have the same ID, you have to update them separately